# a set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with his interior consisting of just one element

Tags: general-topology

I'm wondering about topology, is it possible to have a set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with his interior consisting of  just one element ? Besides is it possible to have a set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is not empty and his boundary consists of just one element ?

Thank you very mch

Answer (score 6):

1. No, the interior of a set is open, and a singleton is not open.
2. Yes, the complement of a single point.

Comment: Assuming $\mathbb R^n$ has the standard topology of course. :)